# Unable to run Solr field analysis (Dspace)

Tags: solr, dspace

I am trying to run some field analysis on the solr associated to dspace.

I am running the following

> curl
>   "http://localhost:8080/solr/analysis/field?field.name=dc.title&field.value=keyword"

I get a 404 answer. Resource not available.

I checked the solrConfig.xml and i got the right config set up:

```
<requestHandler name="/analysis/field" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
```

The line is uncommented.

Is there anything else i can do ?

Comment: You probably need to add the core to your URL -- eg curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/search/analysis/field?field.name=dc.title&field.value=keyword"

Comment: I figured that out and did so, but still does not work

Answer (score 1):

I brought up a the Solr Admin console and ran an analysis.  Here is what the parameters look like.

```
.../solr/#/search/analysis?analysis.query=Smith&analysis.fieldname=search_text&verbose_output=1

.../solr/#/search/analysis?analysis.fieldvalue=handle&analysis.fieldname=search_text&verbose_output=1
```

If you have the Solr Admin (/solr/#/) console enabled on a test server, it can be very helpful.

Here is some documentation on the solr admin UI: [Solr Admin UI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Overview+of+the+Solr+Admin+UI)

This UI provides a great way to understand the contents of your SOLR repos.

To access it, open `http(s)://yourserver.org/solr.`

By default, DSpace restricts access to /solr to the localhost.  You would need to disable the localhost restriction to access this service.

Here are the instructions for bypassing the localhost restriction.
[Instructions Page](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Solr#Solr-Bypassinglocalhostrestrictiontemporarily)

Please read the security warnings on the wiki page.  I would only recommend this option if you have a test server with restricted access.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I do not know what is (/solr/#/) ? neither how to activate it. Never seen it before. How do i know if it is activated or not ? If not activated what should i do ?

Comment: I am able to use the admin console. However it does not work via curl